# Having trouble installing Ububtu

Tags: boot, usb, rufus

I am trying to Install Ubuntu on my HP ProBook which runs off of Windows Enterprise (64 bit). I am diligently trying to follow the directions, but some of the steps are greek to me. I installed Rufus and I even installed Universal USB installer on a 2 GB flash drive. I am attempting initially to have a dual boot option, but will most likely move forward with using Ubuntu permanently. Can someone please help? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to erase Windows  permanently?

Comment: If you want only to try ubuntu the easiest way is to install virutalbox (free sw) on your windows and install ubuntu in it.

Comment: Use the windows 64 bit version. You will find good how-to if you google **Install Virtualbox on Windows**

Comment: @Robert F Melendy PhD Your HP Laptop is running on Win7 or 10? you can install Ubuntu along side them. Have you succeeded making Bootable USB or not?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misinterpreted your question, but when you say you installed Rufus to a 2GB flash drive you do know that you should install those applications to the computer itself and use the application to build a bootable USB. The application shouldn't be installed on the same USB you intend to make bootable. Also if you're installing Ubuntu Desktop, 2GB might not be enough space. I'm not sure what the minimum space is but I would recommend 8GB to be safe.

To get dual boot working with a bootable USB running Ubuntu some guides vary a little but the most common things to check are:

1. You downloaded an Ubuntu ISO file and the file is non-corrupt.
2. Rufus is ran as an administrator
3. You select the Ubuntu ISO as the file to write to the USB
4. You select the USB drive you want to make bootable (it will overwrite all contents on the USB)
5. You wait until Rufus says it's finished writing to the USB and after which you safely eject the USB before removing it.

As long as those 4 steps check out, whatever default/recommended settings probably wouldn't botch an Ubuntu install.

Booting off the USB into Ubuntu most likely requires you to go under the boot menu for your computer and select boot from USB.

After booting the USB. You can follow the install Ubuntu prompts and follow the instructions to setup a dual boot.

*PS. your issue with Virtualbox (if you're absolutely sure you're PC, OS, and Virtualbox application are all 64-bit) you can check the BIOS settings for your computer and ensure any settings regarding virtualization are enabled (may be called something like VT-x, VT-d, AMD-V).*

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry it took me so long to respond to your message. Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. Everything is installed and seems to be running smoothly now. Thank you again.